# osx nosetests not loading module egg

Tags: python, macos, networkx

I have a set of tests which use the networkx module, which is installed as a python egg in my /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ folder.

Loading it in the python interpreter causes no problems:

```
pkerp@toc:~/projects/forgi$ python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkx
>>>
```

When I try and run my tests using nosetests, however, it complains that the module can't be found:

```
pkerp@toc:~/projects/forgi$ nosetests test.forgi.utilities.graph_test:GraphTest.test_shortest_cycle
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named networkx)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/pkerp/projects/forgi/test/forgi/utilities/graph_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
ImportError: No module named networkx

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Any ideas on why this would be the case? The nosetests use a different PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Maybe have have more than one version of Python installed and are calling the wrong one with nosetests?  E.g. one in /usr/bin and the other in /sw/bin?

Comment: That appears to be exactly what's happening, is there a way of telling nose to use the one located under /usr/bin?

Comment: The best way is to (re)install nose using the Python in /usr/bin.

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions, but is there an accepted way of doing that? I'm pretty sure I installed it using macports, but running 'uninstall py-nose' doesn't do much of anything.

Comment: While I'm at it, I might as well also ask why there would be a difference in which packages are loaded by each python version? They both look at the same PYTHONPATH (I hope), and they're both version 2.7.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work by calling nosetests with python:

```
/opt/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nosetests test.forgi.utilities.graph_test:GraphTest.test_shortest_cycle
```

Comment: Awesome! This did trick. Only i did 'python /opt/local/bin/nosetests'.